# Distro upgrade interrupted, cant upgrade to Precise

Tags: installation, upgrade, partial-upgrade

I don't have the opportunity to upgrade by using Live USB and LIve Cd, And since the distro-upgrade was interrupted, No partial upgrade is possible. How can I fix this?

I found an upgrading-tool named `upgrade-manager-kde` and installed it, But I have no idea 
how to make it work, Since it doesn't show on any menu.

Answer (score 0):

Do you still have access to your data in some way.  If so it is urgent that you back up anything you are missing as you have a system that may be unrescueable.  You mow have only one option and that is to use a DVD or a usb.  You are probably going to have to get someone else to get one for you.  If it is possible to boot into your system in any way shape or form, it may well crash without warning, so be very careful of anything you try to do.